# Pandas adding new column based on another column (Wrong number of items passed 19, placement implies 1)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df which contains a column foo. Foo column contains floating point numbers.

I want to add a new column foobar, which is derived by returning the value in the foo column if positive, and returning 0 otherwise.

I have tried the following:

```
test['foobar'] = test[if (test['foo']> 0.0)
test['foobar'] = test[if (test['foo']> 0.0) test['foo'] else 0.0]
```

Both commands threw exceptions. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
test['foobar'] = test['foo'].where(test['foo']> 0.0, 0)
```

Sample:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2.0,-3]})
print (test)
   foo
0  1.0
1  2.0
2 -3.0

test['foobar'] = test['foo'].where(test['foo']> 0.0, 0)
print (test)
   foo  foobar
0  1.0     1.0
1  2.0     2.0
2 -3.0     0.0
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
test['foobar'] = np.where(test['foo']> 0.0, test['foo'], 0)
print (test)
   foo  foobar
0  1.0     1.0
1  2.0     2.0
2 -3.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where`, which keeps values in the Series if condition is true, and take the other value if condition is false:

```
test['foobar'] = test.foo.where(test['foo'] > 0.0, 0.0)
```